# git | move old commit to the past of another branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I incorrectly branched in the past and one commit was left in the start of another branch:

```
* 03431cb (HEAD -> bar) a2
| * d332e4d (foo) b2
| * 9b29ae3 b1
| * 4656a98 a1
|/  
* 6ebca20 (master) root
```

How can I move `a1` out of `foo` into `bar`, so that `bar`'s history is `root -> a1 -> a2` and `a1` is not in `foo`? Is it possible to do it with one single git commit?
This is not pushed so no need to worry about breaking others' local repos.

I first thought about doing a cherry pick of `a1` and then correcting the order between `a2` and `a1`. The issue with this is that those two commits conflicts in my real case scenario and I would have to correct the conflict both when doing the cherry pick and when switching their order.

---

mwe in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

rm -rf .git

git init -b master
echo content > my-file
git add my-file
git commit -m root

git checkout -B foo
echo asd >> my-file
git add my-file
git commit -m a1
echo qwe >> my-file
git add my-file
git commit -m b1
echo zxc >> my-file
git add my-file
git commit -m b2

git checkout master
git checkout -B bar
echo jkl >> my-file
git add my-file
git commit -m a2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the syntax `git rebase --onto x y z`, which means:

> Starting at z, look back thru the parent chain until you are about to come to y and stop. Now rebase those commits, ie everything after y up to and including z, onto x.

In other words, using this syntax, you get to say clearly where to snip the chain. Plus you don't have to switch branches before rebasing. The syntax takes some getting used to, but once you get fluent at it, you'll find yourself using it all the time.

So:

1. Create a temporary branch at a1 just to give it a name: `git branch temp 4656a98`
2. Now rebase b1 and b2 onto root: `git rebase --onto master temp foo`
3. Finally rebase a2 onto a1: `git rebase --onto temp master bar`
4. Now you can delete temp if you like: `git branch -D temp`

Sure, we could save two steps and just do 2 and 3 using SHA number 4656a98 instead of the name temp, but names are nicer.

---

**Proof.**

Starting position:

```
* 9a97622 (HEAD -> bar) a2
| * 83638ec (foo) b2
| * 7e7cbd0 b1
| * 931632a a1
|/  
* 6976e30 (master) root
```

Now:

```
% git branch temp 931632a
% git rebase --onto master temp foo
% git rebase --onto temp master bar
% git branch -D temp
```

Result:

```
* 3a87b61 (HEAD -> bar) a2
* 931632a a1
| * bbb83d0 (foo) b2
| * 5fa70af b1
|/  
* 6976e30 (master) root
```

I believe that's what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do [what I want] with one single git commit?

I assume here you mean *one Git **command*** and not *one Git commit*.  The answer is: no, it's not possible to do that.

> How can I move `a1` out of `foo` into `bar`, so that `bar`'s history is `root -> a1 -> a2` and `a1` is not in `foo`?

See [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522977/1256452) for a way to do this with `git rebase --onto`.

It may, however, help to draw this the way Git sees it.  It's not `root -> a1 -> a2`.  It's `root <-a1 <-a2`.  The name `foo` itself can be moved, but the three existing commits here are carved in stone: no parts of them can be changed.  That's OK since, as you said, none of those commits have been sent anywhere else.

No matter what you do, you must *copy* some commit(s) to new-and-improved commits, with different hash IDs.  You can leave the existing carved-in-stone commits alone provided you're changing *nothing* about them, including the backwards-pointing arrows that are part of the commits.

The root commit (really: `6ebca20`) has no backwards-pointing arrow.  That's what makes it a root commit.  As long as you don't dislike anything about this commit, you can leave it alone—which is good since root commits are a pain to copy.  Both `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase` *can* do that, but it's all a little weird and special-case-y, since the cherry-pick or rebase operation works by comparing a commit's snapshot to its parent's snapshot.  The fact that there is *no* parent of a root commit is what makes it a little weird.<sup>1</sup>

Commit `a1` (really: `4656a98`) points backwards to the root commit.  That too seems OK.

Commit `b1`, however—which is really `9b29ae3`—points backwards to commit `4656a98`.  That's set in stone.  It cannot be changed.  You can make a new and different commit, that you also call `b1`, that instead points backwards to the root commit, and that's what you want to do.

Having done this with `b1`, you now need to copy commit `b2` to a new-and-improved commit, because the existing `b2` (`d332e4d`) points back to `9b29ae3`.  You need a copy that makes the same changes—something cherry-pick will do for you—but that has the new `b1`, whatever its hash ID becomes, as its parent.

Once you've copied `b1` and `b2`, you can point the name `foo` at the copy of `b2`.  Branch names, in Git, simply *point to* some actual, existing commit.  You can change which commit they point to, at any time; whatever commit they point to *is* the last commit in the branch.  Earlier commits are also in the branch by virtue of working backwards through the parent linkage in the *last* commit, then working backwards another step to the parent's parent (or parents' parents or whatever).

Since you *must* copy `b1` to a new-and-improved version, this forces you to copy `b2` as well.  The `git rebase` command runs `git cherry-pick` repeatedly to achieve said copying, then—once all the copying is done—moves the *branch name* to point to the *last copied commit*.  So one `git rebase`, with the right options (`--onto` included), will do the trick for the `foo` branch.

Separately, you *must* copy the existing `a2` to a new-and-improved version.  Having made the copy, you must then move the *name* `bar` to point to the copied `a2`.  One `git rebase` command suffices to do all of these operations as well.

Because `git rebase` can run `git checkout` for you, the minimum number of Git commands needed is, at this point, two.  That leads to the set of commands that matt used: the two extra ones were for convenience.

---

<sup>1</sup>The cherry-pick code itself handles this by using a faked-up "has no files" parent, temporarily, so that as far as the cherry-pick operation is concerned, the "change" made by the commit is *add all the files*.  The rebase code requires the `--root` option, at least in older versions of Git; I'm not sure what has happened here since the sequencer has now learned to do the interactive stuff that used to be in shell scripts.

Comment: Great insight. In particular "The name foo itself can be moved, but the three existing commits here are carved in stone: no parts of them can be changed" was not clear to me yet