# Explain: git rebase --onto base first-segment second-segment

Tags: git, rebase

I was trying to really understand some rebase stuff, and was really stuck on [this snippet](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description):

```sh
git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA
```

How would you explain it? How do you understand it?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522631/git-move-old-commit-to-the-past-of-another-branch

Comment: I think a related approach would be "cherry-pick a range of commits" https://www.google.com/search?q=cherry-pick+range+of+commits

Comment: Rebase is exactly "cherry-picking a range of commits" from the branch point up to the branch head.

Comment: These other answers (from @matt) and @torek are huge, but much more comprehensive. I suppose I could throw my hat in the ring, but I think they have much better answers, despite the length.

Comment: A rule of thumb: one should try to distinguish between Stack Overflow (an encyclopedia of programming facts) and one's own personal blog / notes.

Comment: I'm using this option "Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)". After reading this link, I think it's fair to say stack overflow isn't exactly meant to be a polished, well reviewed encyclopedia. However, that's a desirable goal. On one hand, I believe you and torek's answers ARE better. OTOH, they are very long and intimidating.

Comment: w3schools helped me a long 10 years ago when I first started coding. But, I later discovered https://www.w3fools.com/ There's some balance of accessibility and detail that's simply hard to achieve (Still, I don't disagree with closing this and pointing to your page)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a plain english attempt to re-explain it, for my own future reference.

Imagine this is the call signature:

```
git rebase --onto <base-commit-ish> <first-segment-HEAD> <second-segment-HEAD>
```

This will make `<second-segment>` not dependent on `<first-segment>`.

That is, you'll get a branch structure like this:

```
                 H'--I'--J'  second-segment
                /
                | E---F---G  first-segment
                |/
    A---B---C---D  <base-commit-ish "D">
```

This is useful if you have stacked PRs, but want to "break out" one of the PRs as separate, so they can be independently merged.

If you have a large PR stack, a change is truly independently mergeable (no potential merge conflicts, etc), cherry-pick is a better option.